# what can be the effect on performance of app for using multiple middleware? or what count of middleware would be good for app performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As per documentation mentioned http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples and https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html, there are multiple middleware can be used.
But, If I used 100 middleware in a single route (router level), so will it effect the performance of app.
or any max number of middleware can be used in single route?

Comment: Sure, you can use 100 middleware. The effect on app performance depends on what the middleware does. If they all just call `next` the performance hit is on the order of, say, 100-300 extra function calls (depending on how middleware is implemented, I don't know). I'm voting to close this as too broad/speculative/thought experiment. Do you have a concrete problem to solve?

Answer (score 1):

There is no coded limit to the number of middleware handlers you can install.

You could use 100, but I would argue that you probably would benefit from a different design if you're seriously thinking about 100 separate middleware handlers on a single route.

Yes, having a zillion middleware handlers all for the same route will affect performance if all of them actually run and look at the request.  You're executing 100 functions.  That's not free.